# Returning a select statment from a mssql stored proc using PHP (bool(false))

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am using php to consume a mssql stored procedure, my code works with other stored procs but when I try returning something from this one it just returns bool(false) and not the selected value.

```
    $para = array(array($this->Forename), array($this->Surname), );  
    $result = mssqldb::query("{call usp_NewCustToOrderRemote(?,?)}", $para);  
    $userid = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result);  var_dump($userid);
```

The stored proc basically just inserts the parameters and then selects the new row id

```
    set     @newID = @@IDENTITY
    select @newID
```

I have no control over the stored procedures so I can't add a return value.
When I run the stored proc in management tools it runs fine, when I run in php the row is created.
Oh my db connector class is not using mssql but sqlsrv it's just named incorrectly.
I am I missing something really obvious?

Comment: I was relying to heavy on my class to catch errors, the error I get is 'The active result for the query contains no fields.' So I am a little further forward!

Comment: So all I needed to do was to move to the next result using sqlsrv_next_result($result); and then sqlsrv_fetch_array($result);  again
Simple!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As my stored procedure updated a row and then returned the 'select' I had to use go to the next result as the first result was the row updated.

```
    sqlsrv_next_result($result);
    $id = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)[0];
```

I did add validation as well :)

Comment: You should accept this answer, by clicking on that large tickmark (✔) under the question's score.

Comment: Thanks @Madara Uchiha, I had to wait 2 days to do this.

Comment: I am also under similar situation but a little difference is that my Stored Procdures have PRINT() statements on it. Its a necessity to keep PRINT() for debugging purpose. I wasn't troubled before as I was using mssql_connect. but now after moving to SQLSRV, with these PRINT(), FALSE is returned by sqlsrv_fetch_array() or sqlsrv_fetch(). sqlsrv_next_result($result); won't help me in such situations, and I dont want to remove PRINT(). Do you know a way to allow PRINT()?